How to authenticate to directus using the sdk
I'm building a an ssr Nuxt app and I'm trying to authenticate users so they can access certain content.
Directus and the nuxt app are hosted on different domains.
for now I got this:
directus config :
CORS_ENABLED=true
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=true
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE=true
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_SAME_SITE=lax
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=true
SESSION_COOKIE_SAME_SITE=none

in nuxt :
const directus = createDirectus(directusBaseUrl)
    .with(authentication('cookie', { credentials: 'include' }))
    .with(rest({ credentials: 'include' }));

async function userLogin() {
    try {
        const response = await directus.login(email, password);
        console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}

async function userLogout() {
    try {
        await directus.logout();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}

the userLogin function gets a response back with the access token.
Chrome:
two cookies are createdbut they get deleted when I refresh the page.
In Firefox:
no cookies are created, even after allowing cookies in the browser config.
There are so many things that are unclear, I have a really hard time figuring things out.

We've been struggling with a similar issue.
In our case the solution was to set the CORS_ORIGIN environment variable.
This variable can be either set to true or contain a list of domains (CORS_ORIGIN="array:http://localhost:3000,https://some-other-domain.com")
See Directus Docs / Config / CORS
